# What's the $\otimes$-operator in the proof of Reynolds' transport theorem at Wikipedia?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

In the [proof of Reynolds' transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem#Form_for_a_material_element) at Wikipedia, they use the identities $$\nabla\cdot(v\otimes w)=v(\nabla\cdot w)+\nabla v\cdot w$$ and $$(a\otimes b)\cdot n=(b\cdot n)a\;,$$ where $n$ is probably the outer unit normal field of a given domain boundary.

> But which operator is "$\otimes$" here? And why do these identities hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). If you regard $u$ and $v$ as column vectors it is defined as $u \otimes v = u v^T$.